# Unable to create directory in oracle 12c

Tags: database, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12.2 .I wish to import data pump files. To do that, I wish to create a directory, containing the files and then import. I use the following command to create directory

```
CREATE DIRECTORY dpump_dir1 AS  ‘D:\dumpdir’;
```

I am getting the error as

> SQL Error: ORA-00911: invalid character
>   00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
>   *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
>              letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
>              character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
>              any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
>              (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
>              delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
>              Reference Manual.
>   Could anybody tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Is that Oracle 12.1 or Oracle 12.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes being used in the code you provided are not simple straight single quotes; it's slightly easier to see when formatted as code:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY dpump_dir1 AS  ‘D:\dumpdir’;
```

You can also use your text editor or dump the string to see which chraacters it contains:

```
select dump(q'[CREATE DIRECTORY dpump_dir1 AS  ‘D:\dumpdir’;]', 1016) from dual;

DUMP(Q'[CREATEDIRECTORYDPUMP_DIR1AS‘D:\DUMPDIR’;]',1016)                                                                                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=49 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 43,52,45,41,54,45,20,44,49,52,45,43,54,4f,52,59,20,64,70,75,6d,70,5f,64,69,72,31,20,41,53,20,20,e2,80,98,44,3a,5c,64,75,6d,70,64,69,72,e2,80,99,3b
```

You can see that it's reported at 49 bytes despite being 45 characters long, indicating you have multibyte characters. Before the final [semicolon](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b/index.htm), which is shown as `3b`, you have the sequence `e2,80,99` which represents [the `’` right single quotation mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm), and a bit earlier you have the sequence `e2,80,98` which represents [the `‘` left single quotation mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm).

If you use plain quotes it should work:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY dpump_dir1 AS  'D:\dumpdir';
```

Presumably you copied and pasted the text from an editor which helpfully substituted curly quotes.